# Customizing Yarn container

Tags: hadoop2, spring-data-hadoop

I'm testing spring-yarn integration API and I'm little confused about what is the best practice of Yarn container customization in terms of:

1) If I want to use spring-boot-yarn combo, what is the correct way of telling the spring boot to pick up my implementation of yarn container instead of DefaultYarnContainer...The only way I figured out was via ImportResource annotation at container project class containing main method, which was pointing to spring application xml with declaration:

```
<yarn:container container class="myhadoop.yarn.container.custom.MyContainerImplementation"/>
```

Component scan doesn't work at all...Spring boot was still using DefaultYarnContainer...

2) If I understand Yarn architecture correctly then application master is responsible for launching the container. But If I change DefaultYarnContainer for my implementation then I need to start container manually via run method, nothing was starting it, please what is the correct way?

Thanks a lot in advance for help

Comment: Anyone? Or do I need to add additional information?

Comment: You could also write something about why you want to have a custom container impl. Is there something what existing build-in features doesn't support?

Comment: Think I need to make docs better on this and provide a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If boot is doing auto-configuration for yarn container, there are few ways to define the actual container which defaults to `DefaultYarnContainer`.

Logic of this can be found from here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/blob/master/spring-yarn/spring-yarn-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/yarn/boot/YarnContainerAutoConfiguration.java#L107

1. Use spring.yarn.container.containerClass=foo.jee.MyContainer in yml
2. Create class as bean with name `yarnContainerClass`
3. Create your container impl as bean with name `yarnContainerRef`
4. Create bean as name `customContainerClass` which would be a class as string

Answer (score 0):

Janne, thanks a lot! This way is far more elegant and it works...Here is what I did:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ContainerApplication {

@Autowired
private MyContainerImplementation myContainerImplementation;

@Bean(name="yarnContainerClass")
public Class<? extends YarnContainer> getYarnContainerClass() {
    return MyContainerImplementation.class;
}

@Bean(name="yarnContainerRef")
public MyContainerImplementation getYarnContainerRef() {
    return myContainerImplementation;
}

@Bean(name="customContainerClass")
public String getCustomContainerClass() {
    return "myhadoop.yarn.container.custom.MyContainerImplementation";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ContainerApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

I added MyContainerImplementation into yml as you pointed and my container implementation was started by application master without me running the run method manually, because I see the following lines in the hadoop logs:

```
LifecycleObjectSupport:started
myhadoop.yarn.container.custom.MyContainerImplementation@5e2cd950
.
.
LifecycleObjectSupport: stopped
myhadoop.yarn.container.custom.MyContainerImplementation@5e2cd950
```

Anyway, I have additional question. I wanted to test low-level yarn things like ContainerStateListener and YarnPublisher, but they're not called at all..:-( Here is my test customized container:

```
@Component
public class MyContainerImplementation extends AbstractYarnContainer {
private static final Log log =    LogFactory.getLog(MyContainerImplementation.class);

public MyContainerImplementation() {
    super();

    log.info("...Initializing yarn MyContainerImplementation....");

    this.setYarnEventPublisher(new DefaultYarnEventPublisher() {
        @Override
        public void publishContainerAllocated(Object source, Container container) {
            super.publishContainerAllocated(source, container);
            log.info("Yarn container allocated: "+container.getResource().getMemory());
        }
    });

    this.addContainerStateListener(new ContainerStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void state(ContainerState state, Object exit) {
            switch(state) {
                case COMPLETED: {
                    log.info("...Container started successfully!...");
                    break;
                }
                case FAILED: {
                    log.info("...Starting of container failed!...");
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    log.info("Unexpected container state...exiting!...");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void runInternal() {
    log.info("...Running internal method...");
}
```

}

Do I need to add additional configuration to make ContainerStateListener and YarnPublisher to work?

Comment: You don't need to implement all beans for container, just one is enough. Use of event publisher and state listener are really meant as building blocks what you'd need to call yourself. With boot container execution logic starts from here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/blob/master/spring-yarn/spring-yarn-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/yarn/boot/YarnContainerAutoConfiguration.java#L67 which is a boot `CommandLineRunner` and executes `YarnContainer`. Then it's really up to you to implement higher level features.

Comment: You know, if using boot based container, you don't event need to use any support libraries because from YARN's point of view its yarn container is just a process with exit value.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to implement all beans for container, just one is
>   enough.

You're right. I didn't notice of the following method in SpringYarnConfig:

```
@Override
    public void configure(YarnContainerConfigurer container) throws Exception {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(sycp.getContainerClass())) {
            container
                .containerClass(sycp.getContainerClass());
        } else if (yarnContainerClass != null){
            container
                .containerClass(yarnContainerClass);
        } else if (yarnContainerRef != null) {
            if (yarnContainerRef instanceof YarnContainer) {
                container
                    .containerRef((YarnContainer) yarnContainerRef);
            }
        } else if (StringUtils.hasText(containerClass)) {
            container.containerClass(containerClass);
        }
    }
```

where it's clear that one is really enough...:)

> Use of event publisher and state listener are really meant as building
>   blocks what you'd need to call yourself.

Yes, I see that DefaultYarnContainer is handling notifyXXXX methods(fires up container state changes) calling by himself...Alright, I will definitelly play with it more.

Janne, thanks a lot for help. You provided perfect closer insight into Spring-Yarn.